# Ash & Novinger - Complex Variables - Exercise 2.4.1, possibly dealing with identity theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am self-studying Ash & Novinger's Complex Variables. In [Exercise 2.4.1 (Page 26)](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/CV/CV2.pdf) the authors ask the following exercise:

Give an example of nonconstant, analytic function $f$ on a region $\Omega$ such that $f$ has a limit point of zeroes at a point outside $\Omega$.

It is immediate to see that the function $f: \mathbb C \setminus \{ 0 \} \to \mathbb C$ given by $f(z)=\sin (\frac{\pi}{z})$ has zeros at $1/k$ for each $k \in \mathbb N$. However, the limit of the sequence whose terms are $1/k$ is $0$ does not belong to the domain.

But, I think the authors are trying to illustrate something here. Does it have something to do with the identity theorem? In this case the zero set of $f$ consists elements of the form $1/k$ where $k \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{ 0 \}$. So the zero set of $f$ does not contain any limit points of $\mathbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$. But then the identity theorem has nothing to do here.

What exactly are the authors trying to illustrate here?

Comment: Surely it's just to constrast with what must be true of $f$ if the limit point *were* inside $\Omega$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your observations about the function $f(z) = \sin (\tfrac 1 z)$ are absolutely correct. The set of zeroes of this function have a limit point, but this limit point lies *outside* the open domain on which the function is defined.

The connection to the identity theorem is simply this: the identity theorem *states* that if $\Omega \subset \mathbb C$ is a connected open domain and $f: \Omega \to \mathbb C$ is a holomorphic function on that domain, then the set of zeroes of $f$ has no limit point *inside $\Omega$* unless $f$ is identically zero on the whole of $\Omega$.

The function $f(z) = \sin (\tfrac 1 z)$ defined on the domain $\Omega = \mathbb C \ \backslash \{ 0 \}$ illustrates that, while the set of zeroes of $f$ can't have a limit point *inside* $\Omega$, it can still have a limit point *outside* $\Omega$.

Now if you're reading this, you're probably thinking, "Hang on a minute, the statement of the identity theorem has nothing to do with limit points of the set of zeroes!" Quite possibly, the identity theorem is probably stated in the book you're using as saying that if $f$ is zero on a non-empty open neighbourhood in $\Omega$ then $f$ is identically zero on the whole of $\Omega$.

If this is the source of confusion, then note that the first statement implies the second statement. Indeed, if $f$ is zero on a non-empty open neighbourhood in $\Omega$, then any point inside this open neighbourhood is a limit point of the set of zeroes of $f$, hence by the first statement, $f$ must be identically zero on the whole of $\Omega$. In fact, I suspect that your book proves the first statement and then uses it to prove the second.

Comment: This makes sense! The statement made in the book that I am reading talks about limit points instead of being zero on a non-empty open neighbourhood.

Comment: Cool, good to know